# Is this set open in $R^2$ with Euclidean topology?

Tags: general-topology

$$\left\{ {(x,y)\in R^2 : sin(\frac {x^3}{x^2+y^4}) >0}\right\}$$

In this case, I cannot make my function as preimage of open interval of continuous function.

Any suggestion on approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $f(x, y) = \sin(\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^4})$. Note that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continous. Since your set is equal to $f^{-1}((0, \infty))$ then it is open in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$. But $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so $f^{-1}((0, \infty))$ being an open subset of an open subset is open in the whole space.